# What are the tools and/or advantages of developing your app with a Apple Developer Program account?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Should I get an Apple Developer program account to develop my application or can I do it without it and then submit it obviously through an Apple Developer Progam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to pay for a developer license to use Xcode, compile and run things in the simulator and even to install your software on your devices (macOS, tvOS, watchOS, iOS) for testing and even use as long as you're putting your personal code on your personal devices.

When you do need to pay is when you want one of any of these:

1. Professional Apple Support / code level incidents from Apple Developer Technical Support
2. Verified code signing certificate that let you sign code to run on other computers (whether you use the App Store or not to distribute)
3. iCloud data storage services (sync, core data, cloud data, cloud preferences) for your applications.
4. Presence on the various App Stores to take payments and list your applications publicly under Apple's sales presence on the official stores.
5. TestFlight beta testing services where others in addition to you can test pre-release versions of your software.

Go without the paid access until you need one or more of the above services. See this link for more details - https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev7a05c5ce1

Comment: What do you mean by code level incidents, would that be like technical support for a coding error for example? or a part of an application we do not know how to make?

Comment: @GuillermoRamirezBlonski  Account related / store related support is at https://developer.apple.com/support/ and Code-Level is where you show your code and get support. I believe you get two support incidents per year and can purchase more as needed should you use both yours up before your annual purchase needs to renew.